# C# Moving a Dictionary Into Another File

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, dictionary

```
namespace Webapplication1
{  

Public Class MyDictionaries : WebApplication1._Default
{

public static idictionary<string, label> LabelDict = new dictionary<string, label>()
{

     {"name", label1}

}

}
```

}

Hi Everyone. Im trying to separate a dictionary from my code behind file to a separate class file. but when i do this i get a "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, orproperty" error when i try to build the project. Im not sure what i am doing wrong.

goal: to move the dictionary to a separate class file and still be able to use it as if it where still in the code behind file.

Comment: Label1 Is the Control on my aspx page. how do i change it to static.
(noob)

Answer (score 1):

If `label1` is a non-static variable in the `WebApplication1._Default` class then you cannot access it from a static context. Either `LabelDict` needs to be non-static or `label1` needs to be made static. Probably the latter.